# Something with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I've been working on an mysql chat app in php.
I'm currently working on the ranks for users based on their session id.
Without luck unfortunately,

It does not display any rank.

Me code below.

```
            $SQLGetUsers = $odb -> query("SELECT `chatrank` FROM `chatrank` WHERE `chatrank`='{$_SESSION['ID']}'");
            while ($getInfo = $SQLGetUsers -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $rank = $getInfo['chatrank'];
                    if ($rank == 1)
                    {
                        $rank = 'Owner';
                    }
                    elseif ($rank == 2)
                    {
                        $rank = 'Moderator';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $rank = 'Member';
            }
         }
        }
```

It should display me as being on the 'Moderator' rank
Somehow it does not. http://prnt.sc/dc4iel

Here my mysql table: http://prnt.sc/dc4fzy

How would i correct the issue?

Comment: `var_dump($getInfo)`?

Comment: Please spend a _little_ bit of time coming up with a good title next time. "Something with MySQL" tells us virtually nothing about your question…

Answer (score 0):

change

```
='{$_SESSION['ID']}'
```

to

```
='".$_SESSION['ID']."'
```

**Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please bind the parameters while passing in query.**